# HTML when there is no more space for a cell, start on a new line

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make an 'inventory', and in each 'slot' (td) there will be an item, a bit like this:
[image: picture]

Now as you can see, I have made it to fit a total of 12 products in each "row", I want it to be able to print in 12 products, then start not he next line, and print 12 more, etc.

So it looks like this right now:
[image: picture]

And as you can see, item 13 to 24 are just following along, and I want it to be underneath item 1 to 12, just like the first picture.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code.We will be able to help you more after that.

Comment: html: https://pastebin.com/pfYhkmwA css: https://pastebin.com/Jdy5VMgG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you needle to put 12 cells in a row. Then you need to divide the window widht between 12 and the result you obtain you need to put it as the widht of each cell. Later put  display: inline-block in all the cells.
Hope I help you.